# ¿Cómo evitar que se repita un caracter en un input?

Tags: javascript

Deseo que se pueda colocar una sola vez la tecla **"p"** en un **input**.
Actualmente solo la estoy restringiendo.

```
validarTecla() {
if(event.keycode === 80) {
event.preventDefault();
 }
}
```

Comment: Lo mejor es llevar un contador que dentro de la función valide cuántas 'p' van, y al llegar al límite regresar `event.preventDefaul()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes interceptar el evento `keypress` y comprobar si ya existe una `p`. Si es así y la tecla pulsada es también una `p`, cancelas el evento:

```js
function validarTecla(event) {
  if(event.target.value.toUpperCase().indexOf('P')>=0
      && event.key.toUpperCase() === 'P') {
    event.preventDefault();
  }  
}

document.getElementById('texto').addEventListener('keypress', validarTecla);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="texto">
```